# Large $t$ solution to $\partial_t S(x,v,t) = v \partial_x S + (a+v) \partial_v S + \partial_v^2 S$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, approximation, perturbation-theory

I have the partial differential equation
$$\partial_t S(x,v,t) = v \partial_x S - (v + a ) \partial_v S +  \partial_v^2 S$$
subject to the following boundary conditions:
$$S(x,v,0)=1,$$
$$S(0+,|v|,t)=S(0+,-|v|,t)$$
$$S(H,-|v|,t)=0.$$
These conditions represent reflection and absorption at the boundaries $x=0$ and $x=H$ respectively. The valid spatial domain is $0 \leq x \leq H$ while the valid velocity domain is $-\infty < v < \infty$.

At long times I expect the solution to have an asymptotic form like
$$ S(x,v,t) \sim \exp[-\lambda(x,v) t] $$
for physical reasons, at least for small $a$.
I would like to attempt to derive this form approximately.

One approach I have tried is simply plugging the asymptotic form in the PDE with intent to find a $\lambda(x,v)$ which works. I obtain:
$$ 0 \approx \lambda - v \lambda_x t + (v+a) \lambda_v t + D \lambda_v^2 t^2 - D \lambda_{vv} t.$$
Since by assumption $t \rightarrow \infty$, this seems to imply
$$ \lambda_v^2 \approx 0,$$
or $\lambda = f(x),$ which violates the original assumption that $\lambda = \lambda(x,v)$.

Is there any means by which I might solve this equation perturbatively to obtain the large $t$ solution?